# Problems using CouchDB.NET with C#

Tags: c#, couchdb

I need to create a Database with CouchDB and bind it together with C# for a school project.
It should be with EF or something similar, so i found CouchDB.NET.

I set up the Database local and added some files like the example.

When i run the programm i get a Bad - Http Request 400 and it creates a random empty DB where.

Am I missing something essential?
Or are there any other approaches for this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Example of JSON File in CouchDB. Database is called "animals"**

```
{
"_id": "someId",
"_rev" "somerev",

"species": "Mammal"
"name":"Dog",
"age": "10",
"food": "Meat"
  }
}
```

After that i tried to implement the code on Github from the ReadMe and get the info from the inside a console.

**Programm.cs**

```
using CouchDB.Driver.Extensions;
using CouchDB.Driver.Query.Extensions;

namespace CouchDB
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Usage
            await using var context = new UserContext();
            var animal = await context.Animals
                .Where(r => r.Species == "Mammal")
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.Name)
                .ThenByDescending(r => r.Age)
                .Select(r => r.Name, r => r.Age).ToListAsync();

            foreach (var item in animal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UserContext.cs**

```
using CouchDB.Driver;
using CouchDB.Driver.Options;

namespace CouchDB
{
    public class UserContext : CouchContext
    {
        public CouchDatabase<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(CouchOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
              .UseEndpoint("http://localhost:5984/")
              .EnsureDatabaseExists()
              .UseBasicAuthentication(username: "admin", password: "admin");
        }
    }
}
```

**Animal.cs**

```
using CouchDB.Driver.Types;

namespace CouchDB
{
    public class Animal : CouchDocument
    {
        public string Species { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Food { get; set; }
    }
}
```